# Varnish Cache query on similar url

Tags: varnish

I'm a newbie to Varnish Cache. I have a very basic question around the same.

- I'm making a search query for example like http://test.com?query=apple,orange&store=1234 and the same is fetched and cached in Varnish
- Now again Im making the same request it gets served from Cache with out a backend fetch
- Now if I just pass http://test.com?query=orange,apple&store=1234 , here i just swapped the search keywords. So I'm doubtful, if this query url is unique with previous one or it will be a new backend fetch. Or is there a way we can manipulate the request to match the cached value.

Any help will be great...

Best Regards
Sujith P V

Comment: try this question over at serverfault, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a vmod (a varnish module) which can sort the parameters of the query string.

See https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/essential-vmods-all-varnish-users-should-know-about for an example.

But what you want is to sort the value of a parameter and I dot not think this is possible without knowing the semantic of the value.